# Go to different url depending on value of 2 dropdowns

Tags: php, forms, onsubmit, chronoforms

I'm building a form for an organisation that organises a workshop for teenagers. There is an option to bring one or both parents to the workshop. So for each parent, there's a dropbox to answer the question "Will you participate in the workshop as well?" Depending if one, both or no parents will join, the user will be redirected to a different url after submiting (submit is always in the same place). The form is built with chronoforms in Joomla.

This is the code for the dropdowns, please note that I can't change the values "Ja" or "Nee" because this value is also sent to a database and i'm not allowed to change it. Code for the dropdowns:

```html
    <select class="cf_inputbox validate-selection required" id="select_17" size="1" title="verplicht veld" name="oudersessieouder1" style="width: 193px;">
    <option value="">Make your choice</option>
<option value="Ja">Yes, will participate</option>
<option value="Nee">No, will not participate</option>
    </select><label class="cf_label" style="width: 150px;"> Will this parent join the workshop?</label>

<select class="cf_inputbox validate-selection required" id="select_18" size="1" title="verplicht veld" name="oudersessieouder2" style="width: 193px;">
    <option value="">Make your choice</option>
<option value="Ja">Yes, will participate</option>
<option value="Nee">No, will not participate</option>
    </select><label class="cf_label" style="width: 150px;"> Will this parent join the workshop?</label>
```

And this is the on submit code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>bedankt</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>

if (one parent comes, so one of the 2 dropdown values will be "Ja")
window.location.replace("http://www.website.be/inschrijven-pe-jongeren-1-parent.html")
else if (both parents come, so both dropdown values will be "Ja")
window.location.replace("http://www.website.be/inschrijven-pe-jongeren-both-parents.html")
else
window.location="http://www.website.be/inschrijven-pe-jongeren.html"
</script>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I still need the logic for the on sumbit code. If one parent joins, go to that url, if both parents join, go to that url, and if no parents join, go to that url.

If someone could help me with this, it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the form to submit to different pages or do you want the form to submit to one place then redirect the user?

Comment: To submit to one place and then redirect the user

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear where you have that On Submit code in your form. If you use JavaScript to do the redirection then ChronoForms will never see the submitted data and will not be able to process the results in any way.

If you want ChronoForms to process the data then use code like this in a Custom Code action in the On Submit event:

```
<?php
if ( $form->data['oudersessieouder1'] == 'ja' && $form->data['oudersessieouder2'] == 'ja' ) {
  $form->data['redirect_url'] = JUri::root().'inschrijven-pe-jongeren-both-parents.html';
} elseif ( $form->data['oudersessieouder1'] == 'ja' || $form->data['oudersessieouder2'] == 'ja' ) {
  $form->data['redirect_url'] = JUri::root().'inschrijven-pe-jongeren-1-parent.html';
} else {
  $form->data['redirect_url'] = JUri::root().'inschrijven-pe-jongeren.html';
}
?>
```

Then you can use redirect_url in a Redirect User action.

Note: you should use Serverside Validation before this to check that both values are set.

If you want to do this in JavaScript directly from the browser then you need to put your code above in a function and run that function from the OnChange events of the select drop-downs. At present it will only run when the page loads, not when a selection is made.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this as soon as possible and let you know if it worked. That code is excecuted "after submitting" according to Chronoforms. It's the first time i'm working with Chronoforms os that's part of the reason of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you forget to add else on the second if,

if [condition] 
**else** if [condition] 
else

Comment: True, i typed it fast just to show the logic of what needs to be done.